# how to forward a fluentd log file?

Tags: fluentd

I have a file, which is written by fluentd as format: out_file.

Now I want to forward the content of this file to another fluentd-agent, with tag changed.

But the problem is: the file content will be wrapped again, for example:

the original line is: 

`2017-09-29T20:57:34+08:00   fluentd.test.follow {"from":"A","to":"B"}`

and the new line will be:

`2017-09-29 22:39:52 +0800 center.test: {"message":"{\"from\":\"A\",\"to\":\"B\"}"}`

What SHOULD I do, so I can get the content like this?

`2017-09-29T20:57:34+08:00   center.test {"from":"A","to":"B"}`

Comment: What's the configuration you've tried that gave you that result?

Comment: You could try: https://github.com/TheCodingCompany/php-fluentd-mariadb/releases/tag/v1.0.0
Shows some workaround using exec_filter, which allows to handle events through your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Fluentd offers forwarding to another Fluentd process through a different plugin called out_forward. https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/out_forward

In order to achieve the different structure of Fluentd you should use the record_reformer plugin that allows you to add fields or perform calculations on top of fields

https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/filter_record_transformer